# Solving a complex logarithmic equation

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I am trying to solve the following equation for $x$, with integer $n$.

```
(1 - ((-1 + x)^E x^(1 - x) Log[x]^-E)^(1/(-1 + E)))/(-1 + x) == n
```

Comment: Is $x$ constrained to be real? positive? non-negative?  Can $n$ be zero or negative?  You have not specified such constraints and I wish to verify that this is intentional.  For instance, non-positive $x$ requires some complexity for evaluating `Log[x]`.

Comment: Also, are you sure `E` belongs in the exponent?  It's not wrong persay, just a little bit unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such an equation cannot be solved symbolically by `Solve`, but a solution might be approximately determined with `FindRoot`.

Looking at the left-hand side:

```
Plot[(1 - ((-1 + x)^E x^(1 - x) Log[x]^-E)^(1/(-1 + E)))/(-1 + x), {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which has a (real) domain of `x > 0`, we see that the only integers for which the equation is likely to have a solution are `n == -1, 0`.

```
Table[
 FindRoot[(1 - ((-1 + x)^E x^(1 - x) Log[x]^-E)^(1/(-1 + E)))/(-1 + x) == n,
  {x, 2}],
 {n, -1, 0}]
(*  {{x -> 0.579149 + 7.4303*10^-20 I}, {x -> 2.46043}}  *)
```

The imaginary part is negligible.